# Oracle stored procedures, SYS_REFCURSOR and NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have a legacy Oracle (10.2g) database that I'm connecting to and I'd like to use NHibernate (2.0.1) to give me back objects from a stored procedure. The stored procedure in question uses a SYS_REFCURSOR to return results. According to the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures) this should be doable but I've found a [few](http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2398761) [posts](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/1e5c71502dd547f0/a7908ea36bed6a5e) on the internet that suggest otherwise.

Here's my paraphrased code:

Mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
assembly="OracleStoredProcedures" namespace="OracleStoredProcedures">
    <class name="Person" mutable="false">
        <id name="PersonCode" type="AnsiString" column="PERSONCODE">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" type="String" column="PERSON_NAME" />
        <property name="Surname" type="String" column="PERSON_SURNAME" />
    </class>

    <sql-query name="getpeople">
        <return class="Person" />

        EXEC RS_DB.GETPERSONTEST 

    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RS_DB.GETPERSONTEST (
   io_cursor   IN OUT   sys_refcursor
)
IS
BEGIN
   OPEN io_cursor FOR
      SELECT PERSONCODE, PERSON_NAME, PERSON_SURNAME
      FROM PEOPLE

END GETPERSONTEST;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember this was a bug I also found a couple of years ago when working with oracle, I've tracked back the issue in NH tracker and is fixed but on version 2.1.1GA; Can you verify that this is the same problem you have? 
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-847

Comment: Okay, finally got round to looking at this in our code. I had written a workaround but it was kludgy to say the least. We've since upgraded to NHibernate 3.0 and used the syntax in the link provided ({ call employmentsForRegion(:regionCode) }) and it worked!. Thanks for the late answer :).

Answer (score 2):

What a royal pain this was. This finally worked. I turned the store procedure into a function. Function returned sys_refcursor. Used similar mapping as the OP and name query as below.

```
<sql-query name="getpeople">
 <return class="Person" />

 { ? = call RS_DB.GETPERSONTEST }
</sql-query>
```

[Link](http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate.Test/SqlTest/Custom/Oracle/StoredProcedures.hbm.xml?view=markup)

Comment: I'm having the same trouble and I can't get this solution to work. Can you provide any code?

Comment: index out of range for function that returns sys_refcursor via mapping { ? = call RS_DB.GETPERSONTEST(?, ?) } on NHibernate 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=968248) you should use CALL instead of EXEC.  I have not tried this, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

In your hibernate you state a return type, but Oracle procedures don't return anything. Perhaps if you changed it to a function which returned the ref cursor it would work properly. Also, I believe CALL is the proper syntax. EXEC is a SQL*Plus command and not really a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem today. For us, the fix was to use "CALL" rather than "EXEC", add the round brackets "()" to the procedure call, and wrap the call in curly braces "{}":

```
<sql-query name="getpeople">
    <return class="Person" />

    { CALL RS_DB.GETPERSONTEST() }

</sql-query>
```