# How to execute an Oracle function that returns a sys_refcursor using NHibernate?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

This is the function:

```
FUNCTION GET_ALL(P_USER_ID IN VARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
   C SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN C
    FOR 'SELECT * FROM XYZ WHERE USER_ID = :P_USER_ID'
    USING P_USER_ID;

    RETURN C;
END;
```

I'm trying to call this function using NHibernate, like this:

```
Session
    .CreateSQLQuery("BEGIN ? = PKG.GET_ALL(:P_USER_ID); END;")
    .SetString("P_USER_ID", "SOMEONE")
    .List<XYZ>();
```

Any code, tips or smoke signs are welcome.

PS: I'm using NHibernate 3.3.0.GA

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4237147/232279 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901638/nhibernate-call-function-in-oracle-which-returns-sys-refcursor?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures):

> For Oracle the following rules apply:
>
> > A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a
> >     procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by
> >     using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10. In Oracle you need to
> >     define a REF CURSOR type, see Oracle literature.

There are working tests with full mapping and stored procedure code at https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate.Test/SqlTest/Custom/Oracle

Comment: Yes, and my function returns a result set. And it uses sys_refcursor. But... the docs don't say how you put all these things together.

Comment: You should have an **out parameter**, not a return value. See added link.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon really no way to use function that return sys_refcursor? I support some code and this pattern works for NHibernate 3.1 but doesnt work after update NHibernate